# Generic Filter in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I need to create a function called generic-filter, using the eopl language, that takes two arguments: a predicate and a list. The function should return a similar list but only with elements that satisfy the predicate and must eliminate those that do not comply.

This is what I have so far:

```
(define generic-filter
  (lambda (pred lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (let ([element (car lst)]
              [tail (generic-filter (cdr lst))])
          (if (pred element)
              (cons element tail)
              tail)))))
```

This is ok for these types of list and predicates:

```
> (generic-filter number? ’((1 2 a (b)) 3 4 c 5 d))

’(3 4 5)

> (generic-filter symbol? ’((1 2 a (b)) 3 4 c 5 d))

’(c d)

> (generic-filter list? ’((1 2 a (b)) 3 4 c 5 d))

’((1 2 a (b)))
```

But it won't work with these ones:

```
> (generic-filter null? ’((1 2) () (((4 5) ()))))

(() (( () )))

> (generic-filter even? ’((1 2) 3 (((4 5) 6))))

((2) (((4) 6)))
```

Any tips? thanks.

Comment: (a) application of `generic-filter` is missing an argument (b) are you sure _that_ code is producing those results?

Comment: If `(() (( () )))` and `((2) (((4) 6)))` are desired results, OP wants some "deep filter"- but that would probably return different results for the first three tests. @DavidHume, can you please add more examples (input -> desired output)?

Comment: If you want to recurse into sublists, you need three cases.